# Codeigniter session using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, codeigniter

i know maybe it's a repetitive question, but i would like to know if someone has a good idea for leave user session alive when using ajax calls.

I figured out that when i'm logged and i leave the browser open for 1-2 hours, when i launch ajax calls the session is expired.

i'm using the standard:

```
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 7200;
```

i would like to know if someone has the definitive way to keep alive the user session, better without using interval js functions

Comment: `sess_time_to_update` is how many seconds until the session is regenerated.  `sess_expiration` is the number of seconds the session will last.  Setting `sess_expiration`to 0 will set the session to never expire.

Comment: oh sorry wrong line i was meaning expiration = 7200 ... so you suggest to put it to 0? i'm on CI 2.0+ version, does will session expire on browser call also if session expiration is setted to 0 (and expire on close = TRUE)?

Comment: 7200 seconds = 2 hours, so this makes perfect sense.  As birderic said, either disable the expiration by setting it to 0, or increase from the default number of seconds.

Comment: thanxs guys..My problem is solved reading your conversation..again thanxs.

Comment: Should you want to continue to have session expiration, please see agustinrc89 answer via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls.

Answer (score 2):

The session time is set in the `__construct()` so you could just call any method from the session library when you are making the ajax call and it should update your session expiration time. I would probably just set an "ajax_request" item in the session just to call the library and fire the constructor to reset the session expiration time.

Comment: uhm but i need js ajax calls everytime for refrshing, if you read on top, user birderic has the right answer as i can see :P thx anyway i voted up ;)