# Known bug in session lib of codeigniter 2.1.4?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session

I have worked with *Codeigniter* 2.1.**0** and it has a bug in the session library. With reiterated ajax calls the session expires automatically. There is a fix for this problem, but i have some troubles with it.

I would like to know if in the **latest version** of *Codeigniter* (2.1.**4**) this problem was fixed by Ellislab or it still exists.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to be asking this question/searching in the Codeigniter forum http://ellislab.com/forums/viewforum/49/

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem

[Is there any known bug in the session library of CodeIgniter 2.1.0? Why do I get kicked out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738498/is-there-any-known-bug-in-session-lib-of-codeigniter-2-1-0-why-do-i-get-kicked/16813654#16813654)

it's still kinda buggy ! but ajax problem ahs been solved 
just remmember to put long `sess_expiration` , `sess_time_to_update` in your config .... mine are 86400 and 86500