# How can store javascript variable to php session variables?

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I am having trouble passing javascript arrays and other variables to my php controller. I am doing this in codeigniter. I have assigned some values on javascript like this:

```
var count = ($('#listOfProducts tr').length);
//loop start
var i=0;
grid=$('#listOfProducts input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
    var $row = $(this).parents('tr'); 
    var $trid =$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    rowid[i]=$trid; 
        rowfields.push({itemname: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(), productname:$row.find('td:eq(1)').text(), productdesc: $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(), unitprice:$row.find('td:eq(3)').text(), quantity:$row.find('td:eq(5) input').val(), amount:$row.find('td:eq(6) input').val()});
    i++;
});
```

i have to pass it to my controller so i could save the values to my database... Any help? I am thinking of storing this array as a session variable but I do not know how, considering the client-side and server-side issues.

Comment: Just send it via ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use CI and the best way I found is to send it thru AJAX, like this:

```
$('.your-element').click(function(e){
    var id = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url()+'yourController/youFunction/'+id,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            //YOUR ACTION
        }
    });

});
```

Let us know if you need more specifications.
`NOTE: This method creates problems if you have sessions data going on as every ajax call changes the session id or doubles the time of the session_update`.
To handle this see this post: [HANDLING CODEIGNITER SESSION/AJAX PROBLEMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls)

**Edit:**

For the `base_url()` in JS I wrote this in the index.php file:

```
<script>
function base_url(){
  var url  = '<?= base_url() ?>';
  return url;
}
</script>
```

**Array Edit**

For an Array ajax-call I'd do it using jQuery `$.post()`, like this:

```
$('.your-element').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var demoArray = ['1', '3', '7'];
    $.post(base_url()+'admin/test/', {array_send:demoArray}, function(result){
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

Where the controller `admin/test`is:

```
public function test(){
    print_r($_POST['array_send']);
}
```

Comment: Sir @Mr.Web, assuming i am passing an array "tablefield", how can i get the values in my controller?

Comment: the print works, however when I try to store the values to a variable, it fails...

Comment: @Umpong_1947676 works fine for me this way: `$my_arr = $_POST['array_send']; echo $my_arr[2];`What's the exact issue?
`

Answer (score 1):

There are actually only a few options to pass information from javascript (or the browser that is) to php:

1. Using an Ajax request. This can be both a GET or a POST request (variables in php residing in the `$_GET` or `$_POST` array respectively
2. Using a form: add the data you want to send to a oldschool html form and post it.
3. By magic: put a toothbrush against your head, turn around 7 times and murmur some non-existent words. It might help.