# Codeigniter Session is expired in a short period automatically

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Session is expired automatically in a short period after login and config setting for session in my framework is like this`$config['sess_expiration']= 72000;`.
But it doesn't work and login session is expired before session time is expired.

Comment: Do you have ajax queries running on your application? If so, perhaps this is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls

Comment: I've had few issues with codeigniter session before. Are you running on localhost? Because it could happen due to timezone difference. And which session driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

check your settings with these one

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']          = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']      = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']          = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']            = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']      = 300;
```

Comment: When I change config session with above settings, it's ok but I need to store large amount of data in session table.That's why I need to use session table.So what should I do?

Comment: then you should set that to true, just dont change the following two and then check it $config['sess_match_ip']            = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;