# Updating session cookie during ajax call in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

The following is my ajax call:

```
  remote: 
        {
            url:"http://localhost/my_site/index_page/validate_name",
            type: "post"
        }
```

So in the function validate_name, I set the session cookie as follows:

```
$username = "test1";
$this -> session -> set_userdata('username', $username);
```

Now after the ajax call is completed, I check for the session data in another controller like this,

```
if($this -> session -> userdata('username')=='test1')
```

it turns out that it returns false. Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls try with with.

Comment: I am trying to understand your link. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The link posted ([Codeigniter session bugging out with ajax calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980193/codeigniter-session-bugging-out-with-ajax-calls)) explains that:

> The problem is in the sess_update function of the session class, that generates a new session_id after X seconds. Every page have a session_id, if the session_id expires before the ajax call is made, that call will fail

So the Answer consisted of a class that overrides the session features of Codeigniter, with a warning that you should avoid this. Below is the file that you must create, which allows your ajax call to be completed properly.

**By agustinrc89:**

```
<?php
/**
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * CI Session Class Extension for AJAX calls.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * ====- Save as application/libraries/MY_Session.php -====
 */

class MY_Session extends CI_Session {

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * sess_update()
     *
     * Do not update an existing session on ajax or xajax calls
     *
     * @access    public
     * @return    void
     */
    public function sess_update()
    {
        $CI = get_instance();

        if ( ! $CI->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            parent::sess_update();
        }
    }

}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* End of file MY_Session.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Session.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Make custom session class to override exsiting class or prevent to update ajax call */

    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    
    require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Driver.php';
    require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Session/Session.php';
    
    /*
        Change the following if you want to use a different driver.
    */
    // require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_cookie.php';
    
    class Session extends CI_Session
    {
        protected $CI;
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->CI = & get_instance();
    
            // prevent time update an existing session on AJAX calls.
            $http_x_requested_with=strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']??'');
    
            if ($http_x_requested_with !== 'xmlhttprequest'){
                parent::__construct();
            }
            
        }
    
    }
    
    /* End of file Session.php */
    /* Location: ./application/libraries/Session.php */

/* Else */
/* update session class in system library to prevent ajax call*/

cookie
        // unless it is being currently created or regenerated
        elseif (isset($_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']]) && $_COOKIE[$this->_config['cookie_name']] === session_id() && (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']??'')!== 'xmlhttprequest') )
        {
            setcookie(
                $this->_config['cookie_name'],
                session_id(),
                (empty($this->_config['cookie_lifetime']) ? 0 : time() + $this->_config['cookie_lifetime']),
                $this->_config['cookie_path'],
                $this->_config['cookie_domain'],
                $this->_config['cookie_secure'],
                TRUE
            );
        }
```