# Native-session Modified for code igniter 2.1.4...Does this make sense?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Does anyone see and problems with the modifications for CI 2.1.4? This class was written for 1.7.2 ([Github link](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Dariusz-Debowczyk%27s-Session-Class))

Questions:

1.What is the purpose of regenerate_id? Is it session id rotation?

2.What is the potential problem with session_write_close (as indicated in comment)

3.does this class fully implement session class for CI 2.1.4?

4.Why is sess_expiration used instead of sess_time_to_update for expiration? (Session cookie expires when browser is closed. sess_time_to_update would seem like a better fit for session rotation.

5.Are there any known bugs?

6.If I run an application on a wildcard subdomian (site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com...etc, will the cookies only apply to that subdomain? My main concern is with                 `setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');`

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
* Session class using native PHP session features and hardened against session fixation.
*
* @package     CodeIgniter
* @subpackage  Libraries
* @category    Sessions
* @author      Dariusz Debowczyk, Matthew Toledo
* @link        http://www.philsbury.co.uk/index.php/blog/code-igniter-sessions/
*/
class CI_Session {

    var $flashdata_key     = 'flash'; // prefix for "flash" variables (eg. flash:new:message)

    function CI_Session()
    {
        $this->object =& get_instance();
        log_message('debug', "Native_session Class Initialized");
        $this->_sess_run();
    }

    /**
    * Regenerates session id
    */
    function regenerate_id()
    {
        // copy old session data, including its id
        $old_session_id = session_id();
        $old_session_data = $_SESSION;

        // regenerate session id and store it
        session_regenerate_id();
        $new_session_id = session_id();

        // switch to the old session and destroy its storage
        session_id($old_session_id);
        session_destroy();

        // switch back to the new session id and send the cookie
        session_id($new_session_id);
        session_start();

        // restore the old session data into the new session
        $_SESSION = $old_session_data;

        // update the session creation time
        $_SESSION['regenerated'] = time();

        // session_write_close() patch based on this thread
        // http://www.codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/1624/
        // there is a question mark ?? as to side affects

        // end the current session and store session data.
        session_write_close();
    }

    /**
    * Destroys the session and erases session storage
    */
    function destroy()
    {
        unset($_SESSION);
        if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) )
        {
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
        }
        session_destroy();
    }

    /**
    * Alias for destroy(), makes 1.7.2 happy.
    */
    function sess_destroy()
    {
        $this->destroy();
    }

    /**
    * Reads given session attribute value
    */
    function userdata($item)
    {
        if($item == 'session_id'){ //added for backward-compatibility
            return session_id();
        }else{
            return ( ! isset($_SESSION[$item])) ? false : $_SESSION[$item];
        }
    }

    /**
    * Sets session attributes to the given values
    */
    function set_userdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Erases given session attributes
    */
    function unset_userdata($newdata = array())
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => '');
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Starts up the session system for current request
    */
    function _sess_run()
    {
        session_start();

        $session_id_ttl = $this->object->config->item('sess_expiration');

        if (is_numeric($session_id_ttl))
        {
            if ($session_id_ttl > 0)
            {
                $this->session_id_ttl = $this->object->config->item('sess_expiration');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session_id_ttl = (60*60*24*365*2);
            }
        }

        // check if session id needs regeneration
        if ( $this->_session_id_expired() )
        {
            // regenerate session id (session data stays the
            // same, but old session storage is destroyed)
            $this->regenerate_id();
        }

        // delete old flashdata (from last request)
        $this->_flashdata_sweep();

        // mark all new flashdata as old (data will be deleted before next request)
        $this->_flashdata_mark();
    }

    /**
    * Checks if session has expired
    */
    function _session_id_expired()
    {
        if ( !isset( $_SESSION['regenerated'] ) )
        {
            $_SESSION['regenerated'] = time();
            return false;
        }

        $expiry_time = time() - $this->session_id_ttl;

        if ( $_SESSION['regenerated'] <=  $expiry_time )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Sets "flash" data which will be available only in next request (then it will
    * be deleted from session). You can use it to implement "Save succeeded" messages
    * after redirect.
    */
    function set_flashdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':new:'.$key;
                $this->set_userdata($flashdata_key, $val);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
    * Keeps existing "flash" data available to next request.
    */
    function keep_flashdata($key)
    {
        $old_flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':old:'.$key;
        $value = $this->userdata($old_flashdata_key);

        $new_flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':new:'.$key;
        $this->set_userdata($new_flashdata_key, $value);
    }

    /**
    * Returns "flash" data for the given key.
    */
    function flashdata($key)
    {
        $flashdata_key = $this->flashdata_key.':old:'.$key;
        return $this->userdata($flashdata_key);
    }

    /**
    * PRIVATE: Internal method - marks "flash" session attributes as 'old'
    */
    function _flashdata_mark()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':new:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 2)
            {
                $new_name = $this->flashdata_key.':old:'.$parts[1];
                $this->set_userdata($new_name, $value);
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * PRIVATE: Internal method - removes "flash" session marked as 'old'
    */
    function _flashdata_sweep()
    {
        foreach ($_SESSION as $name => $value)
        {
            $parts = explode(':old:', $name);
            if (is_array($parts) && count($parts) == 2 && $parts[0] == $this->flashdata_key)
            {
                $this->unset_userdata($name);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the question ? where do we have to check in this code ? please be more specific in your question

Comment: I have updated question with specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.What is the purpose of regenerate_id? Is it session id rotation?

The use case is [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) prevention. NativeSession regenerates the session ID every X seconds based on NativeSession::$session_id_ttl attribute value. It reduces impact of session hijacking as the "stolen" session ID is expired and regenerated using regerate_id() after configured time.

> 2.What is the potential problem with session_write_close (as indicated in comment)

In general, session_write_close() is used to get rid of session write lock as soon as all changes to session are done. That may cause multiframe apps load faster (as the session write access is permitted sooner).

You should not add line with session_write_close(), as it will prevent session flashdata mechanism from working correctly.

> 3.does this class fully implement session class for CI 2.1.4?

Not exactly, but it should be possible to use it as a drop-in replacement of CI_Session. I'm using NativeSession with CI2 for 2 production applications without any issues.

Check CI2 Github for CI_Session_native if you are looking for supported CI session handler that delivers similar functionality to NativeSession. I've reviewed the code and it looks like it's partially based on NativeSession. It also contains some security improvements.

> 4.Why is sess_expiration used instead of sess_time_to_update for expiration? (Session cookie expires when browser is closed. sess_time_to_update would seem like a better fit for session rotation.

You seem to refer to CI2 session mechanisms.

- sess_expiration in CI2 allows to set specific time (in seconds) before the session expires after user's last activity
- sess_time_to_update in CI2 allows to set time (in seconds) after user's last activity when the session ID is forced to be regenerated

NativeSession was developed before CI2 and it uses different params than CI Session.

- session_ttl is equivalent of sess_expiration in CI2 session handler
- session_id_ttl is ALMOST equivalent of sess_time_to_update in CI2 session handler (NativeSession does not care about last user's activity - just counts time since last session regeneration)

> 5.Are there any known bugs?

Nothing I'm aware of, although it may contain bugs of course.

> 6.If I run an application on a wildcard subdomian (site1.domain.com, site2.domain.com...etc, will the cookies only apply to that subdomain? My main concern is with  setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');

From [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): "Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'."

I was using this code with application that handles subdomains without any issues.