# Setting flash data session destroys all sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using `ion_auth` library. This code redirects to the login page only when there is a validation error in the form. There is no AJAX in this page, but I already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380188)

Here is my code:

MY_controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
protected $data = Array();
protected $controller_name;
protected $action_name;
protected $previous_controller_name;
protected $previous_action_name;    
protected $save_previous_url = false; 
protected $page_title;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    //save the previous controller and action name from session
    $this->previous_controller_name = $this->session->flashdata('previous_controller_name'); 
    $this->previous_action_name     = $this->session->flashdata('previous_action_name'); 

    //set the current controller and action name
    $this->controller_name = $this->router->fetch_directory() . $this->router->fetch_class();
    $this->action_name     = $this->router->fetch_method();

    if ($this->uri->uri_string() !== 'admin/auth/login' && !$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        //redirect them to the login page
        redirect('admin/auth/login', 'refresh');
    } 
    elseif ($this->uri->uri_string() !== 'admin/auth/login' && !$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {
        //logout if there is any user who is already logged in
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            $this->ion_auth->logout();
        }
        //redirect them to the login page
        redirect('admin/auth/login', 'refresh');
    }
}

protected function render($view_path) { 
    //save the controller and action names in session
    if ($this->save_previous_url) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('previous_controller_name', $this->previous_controller_name);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('previous_action_name', $this->previous_action_name);
    }
    else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('previous_controller_name', $this->controller_name);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('previous_action_name', $this->action_name);
    }

    $view_path = $view_path. '.php'; //set the path off the view
    // echo "<center><h1>".$view_path."</h1></center>";
    if (file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/' . $view_path)) {
        $this->data['content'] .= $this->load->view($view_path, $this->data, true);  //load the view
    }       
    $this->load->view("layouts/main.tpl.php", $this->data);  //load the template
}
}
```

types.php

```
class Types extends MY_Controller {
public function add()
{
    $categoryId = $this->uri->segment(4);
    if(isset($categoryId) && !empty($categoryId))
    {
        $data['categoryId'] = $categoryId;

        $this->data['title'] = lang( 'add_type' );  

        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'nameAR', lang( 'name_ar' ), 'trim|required|min_length[2]|xss_clean' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules( 'nameEN', lang( 'name_en' ), 'trim|required|min_length[2]|xss_clean' );

        if ( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ) {
             $this->session->set_flashdata( 'msg_class', 'alert alert-danger' );
             $this->session->set_flashdata( 'msg', validation_errors() );
            //$data['msg_class'] = 'alert alert-danger' ;
            //$data['msg'] = validation_errors();

            $this->load->vars($data);
            $this->render( 'admin/types/add' );
        }
        else {
            $postedArray = $this->input->post( NULL, TRUE );
            //check if name already exists
            if(count($postedArray) > 0)
            {
                $this->checkIfTitleExists($postedArray['nameAR'], $postedArray['nameEN'], 'admin/types/add/'.$categoryId, 0);

                //insert
                $postedArray['cat_id'] = $categoryId;

                if ( $this->type_model->insert( $postedArray ) ) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'msg_class', 'alert alert-success' );
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'msg', lang( 'insert_success_message' ) );
                    redirect( 'admin/types/add/'.$categoryId, 'location' );
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'msg_class', 'alert alert-danger' );
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'msg', lang( 'insert_error' ) );
                    redirect( 'admin/types/add/'.$categoryId, 'location' );
                }                  
            }
        }
    }
    else{
         redirect( 'admin/categories/index/3', 'location' ); //show real estate categories
    }
}
}
```

this is where errors should be in the view:

```
 <?php if ( $this->session->flashdata( 'msg' ) ) {?>
                     <div id="divMessage" class="<?php echo $this->session->flashdata( 'msg_class' );?>" >
                     <?php echo $this->session->flashdata( 'msg' );?></div>
                     <?php }  ?>
```

Here is also my config part for sessions:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 604800; // 7 days
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

So, what is the problem?

Comment: any message error taht you could provide us?

Comment: No error messages at all, it just forces user to logout.